# Get variables of parent class php from Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I've the followings classes:

- abstract class `utility`, which contains general functions (e.g. database connection)
- class `get_conf`, which returns the main variables that I will need almost everywhere (e.g. language, login status)
- class `get_data` to handle the query to the database and return the results.

This is in my index file:

```
$init = new get_conf();

$lang = $init->lang;
$status = $init->status;
(...)

$config = new get_data($lang,$status);
```

This is the construct of class `get_data`.

```
class get_data extends utility {

    public function __construct($lang = NULL,$status = NULL) {
        $this->lang = $lang;
        $this->status = $status;
    }

...
```

Everything work fine, but I don't know how to handle at best during an ajax call.
After instantiate the class that I need,

```
$config = new get_data();
```

What is the best way to get `$lang` and `$status`? At the moment I'm calling again the functions that define their values - `get_language()`, `check_login()`.

But there is a better way? Should I use sessions? It doesn't sound good to me call every time those function, especially when I have multiple ajax calls in the same page.

EDIT: I'm sorry, is my fault cause I formulated the question in the wrong way. What I would need is to get the variables from Ajax and ok, but I would need to use them in the class

For example, in the class `get_data` I've this function:

```
public function get_category($id_cat) {
    $q = "SELECT category FROM p_category WHERE id = '".$id_cat."' AND code = ".$this->lang.";
    return $this->exe_query($q);
}
```

Cause I'm calling this function both from Ajax and not, depending on the situation, `$this->lang` is defined only when I call it out of an Ajax request. And even using static var doesn't work with Ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Write the following member function inside get_data class:

```
public function getCVar($var){
  $c = new get_data();
  eval('$tmp = $c->'.strtolower($var).';');
  return $tmp;
  }
```

Then you can get the variables value like below:

`echo get_data::getCVar('lang');
echo get_data::getCVar('status');`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
class get_data extends utility {
    static $lang = null;
    static $status = null;
    public function __construct($lang = NULL,$status = NULL) {
        if($lang !== null){
            self::$lang = $lang;
        }
        if($status !== null){
            self::$status = $status;
        }
    }
}

$config = new get_data($lang,$status);
echo get_data::$status;
echo get_data::$lang;
```

Comment: Thank you I think it works great! I'm just getting Notice: Undefined property: get_data::$lang where in the rest of the class I have $this->lang, $this->status, but I guess I should just replace all those with self::lang and self::status, right?

Comment: Yes. Static properties necessary to cause through **self ::**